# How do I add a char to every item in a list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

As an exercise to see if I understand the `map` function I wanted to add a char 'a' to every item in the range A-Z.

Well appearently I dont because I get these exceptions which I dont undestand as output:

```
Prelude> map (++ 'A')['A'..'Z']

<interactive>:46:9:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:46:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘'A'’
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(++ 'A')’
    In the expression: map (++ 'A') ['A' .. 'Z']

<interactive>:46:14:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:46:1)
    In the expression: 'A'
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘['A' .. 'Z']’
    In the expression: map (++ 'A') ['A' .. 'Z']

<interactive>:46:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:46:1)
    In the expression: 'Z'
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘['A' .. 'Z']’
    In the expression: map (++ 'A') ['A' .. 'Z']
Prelude>
```

I understand ++ is the concat operator for lists which includes strings.

Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: You can't append characters. Perhaps you meant to use strings. Use double quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say `++` is the concat operator for lists. It takes a list, and adds another list to the end, for example, `[1, 2, 3] ++ [4, 5, 6] == [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. The issue in your case is you're attempting to add a character to a character - not a list to a list.

A string is a list of characters, so instead we could do:

`map (\x -> [x] ++ ['A']) ['A'..'Z']`

However, this is a bit cumbersome and ugly. If we just want to add one item to the start of a list, we can use the `:` operator. In this way, we can invert the problem. Instead of adding 'A' to the end of each character, we can add the character to the start of 'A'.

For example:

`map (\x -> x : "A") ['A'..'Z']`

We can then ETA reduce this to:

`map (: "A") ['A'..'Z']`

As you may notice, I have replaced 'A' with "A". "A" is a list of characters, which happens to be one element long. Now, we can add one character to the list, the input, instead of having to convert both to lists first.

And we can see, it works as expected:

```
Prelude> map (: "A") ['A'..'Z']
["AA","BA","CA","DA","EA","FA","GA","HA","IA","JA","KA","LA","MA","NA","OA","PA","QA","RA","SA","TA","UA","VA","WA","XA","YA","ZA"]
```